# What is an idiomatic way to update hash keys in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, hash, iterator, refactoring, enumerable

When iterating though a hash, keys cannot be changed. Suppose you want to add '_new' to each key:

```
hash = { 'a' => 1, 'b' => 2 }

new_pairs = Hash.new

hash.each do | k,v |
  new_pairs[ k + '_new' ] = v

  hash.delete k
end

hash.merge! new_pairs
```

Is there a cleaner, more idiomatic ruby-like way of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need in-place mutations (`merge!`). I'd do something like this:

```
hash = { 'a' => 1, 'b' => 2 }

hash2 = Hash[hash.map{|k, v| [k + '_new', v] }]

hash2 # => {"a_new"=>1, "b_new"=>2}
```

Comment: @BSeven: Yep, exactly.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot directly iterate though a hash while modifying it, but you can iterate over `keys`.

```
hash.keys.each{|k| hash["#{k}_new"] = hash.delete(k)}
```

Comment: In sifting through the various adjectives I might use with your solution, I settled on 'cute'. (Nice.)

Comment: Yes, distinctly cute.

Answer (score 2):

Take your pick!

```
    hash = hash.keys.reduce({}) {|h,k| h[k + '_new'] = hash[k]; h}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
hash.map { |k, v| {"#{k}_new" => v} }.reduce(:merge)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do as below :

```
hash = { 'a' => 1, 'b' => 2 }
nw_hash = Hash.new { |hsh, key| hsh[key+'_new'] = hash[key] }
hash.keys.each{|e| nw_hash[e] }
nw_hash
# => {"a_new"=>1, "b_new"=>2}
```